# XML Serialization in Unity iOS exception

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, xml-serialization

I am trying to read/write an xml file to store some data for my game. Here is the object i am trying to store:

```
public struct EndRaceData
{
        // Data used to display section by section data
        public List<SpeedRecord> speedRecords { get; set; }
        // Data used for making a map
        public List<KeyValuePair<String,SpeedRecord>>recordsByname { get; set; }
        // Taken from Datatracker.instance
        public List<KeyValuePair<String,List<DataRecorder.GPSPoint>>> pointsPerChallenge { get; set; }
        // Taken from DataRecorder.instance
        public List<SpeedSegment> averageSpeeds { get; set; }
        // Taken from IPlayer..
        public float caloriesburnt { get; set; }
        // Taken from Datatracker.instance
        public float topSpeed { get; set; }
        // taken from Datatracker.instance
        public float points { get; set; }
        // taken from Datatracker.instance
        public string difficulty { get; set; }
        // taken from Datatracker.instance
        public float completedPercentage { get; set; }
        // challenge-specific data
        public int passedChallenges { get; set; }
        // Datatracker.instance
        public int failedChallenges { get; set; }
        // Datatracker.instance
        public int  fastChallengesPassed { get; set; }
        // Datatracker.instance
        public int slowChallengesPassed { get; set; }
        // Datatracker.instance
        public int keepChallengesPassed{ get; set; }
        // Datatracker.instance
        public string startTime { get; set; }
        // Datatracker.instance
        public string endTime   { get; set; }


        public float distanceTravelled { get; set; }

    public string filePath {get; set;}
}
```

Where SpeedRecord is:

```
public struct SpeedRecord
{
        public float speed;
        public float distance;
        public string name;
        public string sectionStartTime, sectionEndTime;

        public SpeedRecord (string name, float speed, float distance, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
        {
                this.speed = speed;
                this.name = name;
                this.distance = distance;
                this.sectionStartTime = startTime.ToString ();
                this.sectionEndTime = endTime.ToString ();
        }

        public override string ToString ()
        {
                return string.Format ("{0}\r\nAVG speed : {1} km/h\r\nDist : {2} m\r\nTime : {3} -> {4}\r\n", this.name, this.speed, this.distance, this.sectionStartTime, this.sectionEndTime);        
        }
}
```

SpeedSegment is:

```
public struct SpeedSegment
{
        public float speed;
        public float time;
}
```

and finally GPSPoint is:

```
public struct GPSPoint
    {
            public float lat;
            public float lon;
            public float accuracy;
            public float time;

            public GPSPoint (float lat, float lon, float acc, float time)
            {
                    this.lat = lat;
                    this.lon = lon;
                    this.accuracy = acc;
                    this.time = time;
            }
    }
```

The issue I am having is that everything works perfectly on all platforms except for iOS. I can generate my XML files without any issues on all platforms, but when I try to read them on iOS, I get the following error:

> XmlException: Document element did not appear.  Line 1, position 1.
>   at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.Read () [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read () [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent () [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadRoot ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader reader) [0x00000] in
>   :0

Any suggestions as to what might be causing this?

Im guessing it is something specific to iOS since the solution works fine on Android, Standalone and inside the editor.

**Edit**- Here is the XML file i am trying to parse:

http://hastebin.com/tilareququ.xml (Too long to paste directly)

Finally, here is the methods I use to serialize/deserialize:

```
    public static void WriteXML (string fileName, object obj)
    {
            using (var f = File.Create (fileName)) {
                    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer (obj.GetType ());
                    ser.Serialize (f, obj);
            }
    }

    public static T ReadXML<T> (string fileName)
    {
            using (var f = File.Open (fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
                    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer (typeof(T));
                    return (T)ser.Deserialize (f);
            }
    }
```

Comment: can you post the xml file you're attempting to read?

Comment: Its too long to be posted here, should I store it somewhere and provide a link to it?

Comment: posting the first few lines would be okay or at least better than nothing, just to verify if the error is likely to be caused by the xml file itself. In addition, a http://jsfiddle.net/ with the full content would be helpful to check if the XML is malformed or the likes..

Comment: I am running into a similar issue like this. Did you solve this one?

Comment: I did not, I ended up using json files instead.

Answer (score 1):

My educated guess is that you included the [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (Unicode Byte-Order Mark) in your document. These are 3 bytes that specify the encoding of the file. The BOM is written at the beginning of the XML file. Therefore, when reading the file with XMLTextReader, it complains that the document didn't start with an element, because the BOM was read instead.

My advice would be to specify that you don't want the BOM to be written when writing XML files. You can do this by passing false to UTF8Encoding: `new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false);`

Example:

```
XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(streamReader, new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false));
//now the BOM is not written to your XML file
```

Comment: I cannot check it right now but I will try it and mark this as the correct answer if it is indeed the issue :) What I fail to understand thou is why this would only be an issue on iOS and not on Android or Windows/OSX

Comment: Unfortunately, platform or language specific differences happen all the time and I'm sure you'll stumble over further pitfalls soon enough. Anyway, I hope that fixed it for you.

Comment: Hi again, I added the methods I use to serialize/deserialize, which use the XMLSerializer rather than the XmlTextWriter that you provided. Do you know if the XMLSerializer can be told not to use the BOM? Thank you

Comment: Added your piece of code and checked that the XML file did not contain a BOM anymore but the same error still pops up i'm afraid.

Comment: Couldn't find a working solution for this issue. Storing data in a text file and parsing it back to relevant data myself instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use StreamReader rather than File.Open?`StreamReader re = new StreamReader(fileName,  System.Text.UTF8Encoding);`

Comment: I have not. Will try and let you know :)